# Estou tentando mudar o valor da propriedade de um objeto com o ng-click:

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Quando clicar no botão, quero mudar o valor da propriedade `addButton` dentro da variável `gens` pra `true`.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Segue o exemplo no [Codepen](http://codepen.io/vinicius/pen/pjyjXP).

Answer (score 2):

Devido ao data-binding do Angular, modificando o valor de uma variável no escopo, essa mudança será automaticamente refletida na *view*.

Ou seja, para mostrar o botão, basta percorrer os itens contidos dentro de `$scope.products`, alterando o valor de *addButton* de cada um deles para true, e, automaticamente, os botões irão aparecer.

Segue um CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyqwoW

Comment: Opa ! Legal Lucas, valeu. xD